# can't import MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Hi I ran the following scripts from macports and still can't run the `import MySQLdb`. Any idea what the problem could be?

```
sudo port install py26-mysql 
sudo port install mysql5-server

>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are not using Macports Python, but OSX native Python installation, or wrong version of Python from Macports.

Make sure you launch Python interpreter 2.6 from Macports.